# Dynamic Lightning Page Visibility Rule $User.UserRole

Tags: roles, flexipages, lightning-page

I am attempting to show/hide a component on my Lightning Page using a `visibilityFilter` attribute based on `$User.UserRole.DeveloperName`

I have carefully compared the running User's Role `DeveloperName` to the `DeveloperName` (using `_`) however when I set the following:

```
<visibilityRule>
   <criteria>
     <leftValue>{!$User.UserRole.DeveloperName}</leftValue>
     <operator>EQUAL</operator>
     <rightValue>EEE_Manager</rightValue>
   </criteria>
</visibilityRule>
```

[image: Visibility based on User Role]

And Login as the user, the component is not displayed. If I update the criteria to `Not Equals` or `NE` operator, the component is displayed?

**Note** If I remove the visibility filter complete, the component is displayed- so I don't believe it's an access issue.

The user's profile DOES NOT have `View all Data`, or `View Role and Role Hierarchy Permissions`- if I enable `View Role and Role Hierarchy Permissions` the component appears?

So `View Role and Role Hierarchy` permission is determined for the user to see the name of their own role? ‍♂️

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if I enable View Role and Role Hierarchy Permissions the component
> appears?

Yes, and I've tested this in my dev org.

> So View Role and Role Hierarchy permission is determined for the user
> to see the name of their own role?

Yes, `View Roles and Role Hierarchy` permission is required for a user to see their own role name. Note that this permission would normally open up access to view all the roles and role hierarchy. However, if a user has this permission & not the `view setup and configuration` permission, then this user

- can see the role name (as a hyperlink) in their settings page (under `My Personal Information > Advanced User Details`/ see screenshot below).
- **cannot** navigate to the role details page by clicking on the hyperlink.

[image]

If you revoke the `View Roles & Role Hierarchy` permission, then the role will **not** be displayed in the advanced user details page (unlike shown in the screen shot above). Instead, the role field will display blank.

Comment: Great - thanks for the comprehensive answer!